# SSIS package that will create automatic a excel file for every city?

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I am doing a SSIS package, that will read the Data from the SQL table and will create a Excel file for every city of a country, in that file will keep all the information of that city. My Question is how you create about 175 Excel file, I know  how to create 2 or 3 with the Conditional Split ? but 175

Comment: I would use script task

Answer (score 0):

**short summary**

you will prepare query to obtain dataset with cityID, cityName, iterate this dataset, for each dataset you will obtain data by cityID, and transform this resultset into dynamicaly named XLS file.

**detailed workflow**

1) prepare empty xls layout file, which will be used for preparation of rest of files (you setup header rows, e.g.)

2) prepare package variables:

a) cities - object

b) city_id - int

c) city_name -  varchar(x)

d) xls_layout_path - path to empty xls file - setup accordingly where you prepared file on your sql server filesystem

e) xls_current_path - path to destination xls file - with help of expression, you setup dynamic path to this file, whereby city_id, and/or city_name could be used as part of filename

3) **sql query task** - you query all cities, e.g. cityID, cityName. You setup sql query task to return data set, and this dataset to object variable
see this for more details:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-execute-sql-task-to-generate-result-sets/

4) then you iterate cities variable with help of **Foreach loop container** whereby you store cityID and cityName in corresponding package variables

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5232.ssis-looping-over-object-variables-with-as-ado-enumeration-in-foreach-loop-container.aspx

5) inside loop container you prapare following:

5a) prepare empty file with help of **File system task** - you will copy xls_layout_file to dynamically set xls_current_file (e.g. you will prepare destination file with city name) - see Expression to setup connection string (path)

5b) inside **Dataflow task**

- as your source query data for current city with help of cityID and
  parametrised query
- use transformation if necessary (e.g. transform codepage excel is able process - this relates to collaton of your database - we use to have local collation - e.g. Sloval_CI_AS)
- set xls file as destination with connection string dynamicaly set to xls_current_path (with help of expressions)

Comment: Ivan, I have all ready the field in the SQL table call city, so the SSIS will read a record if is equal to the city of Miami for example, the information of that record will go to the Miami Excel workbook,...another Example in the SQL  Table a record can contain the following information   name->Ivam , Lastname->Kristof, Address-> N street , City->Miami, you know what I mean ?

Comment: Luis, pls, maybe it helps when you describe your current tables, at leas CREATE TABLE queries, to help me understand your DB structure.

Comment: Basically there is no problem to prepare parametrised query where you use city name (not "city id") as parameter to get resultset for this city which will be transformed to destination xls file.

Comment: I have a field with the name of the city all ready in the table, so will follow yours advice and let you know how its go, Thanks

Comment: @LuisDelgado just forgot to mention as you will be dynamicaly setting connection string, etc. you have to set **Delay validation** property to TRUE for data flow task. More on this topic: http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/delay-validation-property-in-ssis/